# When using "Google Drive for desktop" and I sync a "Folder from your computer", can that folder also be synced with other computers?

Tags: data-synchronization, google-apps

"Google Drive for desktop" has two different sync options:

(1) ***"Folders from Drive":*** This isn't actually an option, since you have no option to turn it off. It has two modes, though. One mode is called "Stream files" and one mode is called "Mirror files". Neither of these are the feature that I want to ask about, however. I understand how to use them.

(2) ***"Folders from your computer:"*** With this option, you can select an arbitrary number of specific folders located anywhere on your computer that you'd like synced to Google Drive.

My question is about feature #2 above. It works great. Except that I can find no way to make this feature sync the same folder across two or more computers. The files that are synced using this feature end up in Google Drive (as seen via the web interface), not under "My Drive", but rather under "Computers". And there is one folder under "Computers" for each computer that you use with *Google Drive for desktop*.

There seems to be no way to tell Google Drive that I'd like, for instance, ~/'My Folder' on "My Desktop Mac" to be considered to be the same folder as ~/'My Folder' under "My MacBook".

Am I missing something? I really would like to make this work, and it seems as if it would be easy for Google to implement.

Thanks.

P.S. Yes, I understand that I can do something like make a symlink on both "My Desktop Mac" and "My Macbook" that links to ~/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-my-email-address@gmail.com/'My Drive'/'My Folder', but for various reasons, I'd prefer not to have to do it that way.

P.P.S. This is how things work on the latest version of Monterey using the latest version of *Google Drive for desktop". Specific details may differ a bit with older versions Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

> P.S. Yes, I understand that I can do something like make a symlink on both "My Desktop Mac" and "My Macbook" that links to ~/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-my-email-address@gmail.com/'My Drive'/'My Folder', but for various reasons, I'd prefer not to have to do it that way.

Since you said this, my response may not be an acceptable solution. Yet I just share what I'm happy with, as there doesn't seem to be a response so far.

Environment verified the following Google Drive desktop app (GDA) behavior: Mac OS (Big Sur)

Steps (on your local host)

1. Have the cloud files somehow.  Call the top directory of this as "GoogleDrive".
2. Move "GoogleDrive" folder to your ideal path.
3. Open `Terminal` app (on my host it uses `zsh`).
4. Terminate `GDA` (for safety, I recomment verify no process running by e.g. `ps -ef|grep -i "google drive"`, not just GUI).
5. Create a symlink from `GoogleDrive` to `/Volumes/GoogleDrive`. Full command may look something like `sudo ln -sf ~/%path_to_%/GoogleDrive /Volumes/GoogleDrive`.
6. Start `GDA`.
7. On `GDA` GUI, select "Preference" -> "Google Drive" -> Check "Mirror files" then proceed to confirm.
8. Sync should start. Let it sync, do your verification.

I've been using this setting for a few years, so far no issue.

For detail I've logged my entire process in [hut_10sqft#876](https://github.com/kinu-garage/hut_10sqft/issues/876) if you need (note in my case there's one more complication i.e. placing GoogleDrive folder under Dropbox path, which works but may come with many issues to workaround).